# Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is problem 1.4.10 in Abbott's Understanding Analysis 1st Edition. I am assuming

Theorem 1.4.13

i) If $A_{1},A_{2},\dots,A_{m}$ are each countable sets, then the union $A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup\dots\cup A_{m}$ is countable.

ii) If $A_{n}$ is a countable set for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ is countable.

Proof:

Let $A_{k}$ be the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose maximal element is $k$.

Ex: $A_{1}=\{\{1\}\}$, $A_{2}=\{\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$, $A_{3}=\{\{3\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\},$

$\dots, A_{k}=\{\{k\},\dots,\{k-1,k\},\dots,\{1,2,\dots,k-1,k\}\},\dots$.

By construction, $A_{k}$ is countable for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$. (More precise, each is finite by the bijection $f_{k}:A_{k}\to\mathbb{N}_{2^{k-1}}$)

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Also let $A_{0}=\emptyset$.

Then, $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}$ is countable since each $A_{k}$ is countable by ii) in Theorem 1.4.13.

Therefore, $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\cup A_{0}=\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}A_{k}=\mathcal{A}$ is countable by i) in Theorem 1.4.13.

Comment: This is fine, as you rely on the fact that ordered finite non-empty sets have a maximal element, and that each $A_k$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(\{1,\ldots,k\})$, which is finite.

Comment: Thank you! My friend and I are going through the book, and this one really stumped us.

Comment: My proof of choice for this statement is finding a bijection between $A$, the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$, and $\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$.